# Websites linked to our website can't see view count in Google Analytics

Tags: ssl, https, seo

Since we have set up our website with SSL certificate, we moved our whole website to https protocol. The problem is since we moved our website many of other websites which have links on our website can't see number page views coming from our website.

Https is set up Nginx and Wordpress, and our GA tracking code is working for us very well. I reallt can't figure out why is this happening.

Anybody had this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to force http to redirect to https:

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name your.server.com;
    rewrite     ^   https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
}
```